# Can thttpd support multipart/form-data?

Tags: c++, c, multipartform-data, thttpd

I could successfully setup thttpd and tested a sample page with form. If I replace the input element with type "file" and post a file upload, thttpd closes the connection without any response but the same works if the input type is text.

So does thttpd supports file uploading ie handling of multipart/form-data? If yes how to handle the same using a cgi written in C/C++?

Comment: As far as I know, this has nothing to do with the webserver and everything to do with your cgi program.